# How to modify an existing rule in SonarQube?

Tags: php, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

I wonder how to modify an existing rule in SonarQube.
For example this rule:

```
( Remove this commented out code )
/* ..... commented code ..... /*
```

I want to modify this rule, to ignore the commented code containing `@any_thing` like this:

```
//@anything
/* ..... commented code ..... /*
```

Or like this:

```
/* @anything 
 ..... commented code ..... /*
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify an existing rule. A workaround is to [write a custom rule](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+PHP).

However, you should first seriously consider whether the behavior you want to achieve is really specific to your own environment. If that's not the case, you can suggest a change to the existing rule by joining the [SonarQube google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube).